# Display image with external source in iOS with Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

All I'm trying to do is display the following image with the source set to an external location (AWS S3) in an iOS emulator using Ionic/Cordova/Angular:

```
<img src="https://miyagi-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/madeline-profile"/>
```

**I've tried the following:**

1) Added AmazonAWS to Cordova's whitelist, but I'm pretty it's already covered by the first line:

```
<access origin="*"/> <!-- existing -->
<access origin="*.amazonaws.*" />  <!-- added this -->
```

2) Tried removing the protocol altogether like so:

```
<img src="miyagi-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/madeline-profile"/>
```

3) Tried using a different image from a standard http protocol:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Portrait_placeholder.png"/>
```

4) Tried using ng-src instead of src:

```
<img ng-src="https://miyagi-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/madeline-profile"/>
```

**Full Page for Reference:**

```
<ion-view class="has-header" view-title="Create Class">
  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="ClassName">Class Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="classInformation.name" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="ClassPhoto">Class Photo: </label>
        <div class="button" ng-file-select ng-file-change="upload($files)" ng-multiple="multiple">Select File</div>
        <img src="https://miyagi-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/madeline-profile" height="150px"/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="description">description: </label>
        <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="classInformation.description" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="rate">rate: </label>
        <input type="text" name="rate" ng-model="classInformation.rate" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="date">date: </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" ng-click="setDate()" ng-model="classInformation.date" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="time">time: </label>
        <input type="text" name="time" ng-click="setTime()" ng-model="classInformation.time" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="location">location: </label>
        <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="classInformation.location" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="createClass()">Create Class</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: are you using ionic live reload ?

Comment: This is after I run ionic build ios and launch the emulator in Xcode. I believe in my setup, ionic live reload only runs when I call ionic serve for browser testing. I have no issues in the browser.

Comment: "ionic run -l" can be called on a device too. You can actually set up live reload on your device too. Regarding your question; you dont have your <img src="path/to/file/filename.jpg"> , YOU NEED TO PUT FULL PATH OF THE IMAGE.

Comment: Can you try using "ng-src" instead of "src" ?

Comment: Yes I was using ng-src originally with no luck. Forgot to add that to the list of things I've tried - thanks. I've edited the post.

Comment: https://miyagi-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/madeline-profile      is not a image. its just a path, where is the image ?where is the extension ?

Comment: Good point but I've tested that case in things i've tried number 3) <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Portrait_placeholder.png"/>  and just tried it again with <img ng-src="http://sites.duke.edu/wcwp/files/2013/12/article-rooney.jpg" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after restarting Xcode.